# How To refresh an angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building a mobile app using `ionic 4` and it's two languages `ar` and `en`, the menu drawer is a pre-built component.

So I need to refresh the drawer component to get's the right styles based on the dom direction `rtl` or `ltr`

What I'm doing now is just `location.reload` reloading the whole app but I don't think that a good approach for doing that

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way to do is to call ngOnInit something like

```js
fn() {
    this.ngOnInit();
}
```

Or try this

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefreshComponent', { skipLocationChange: true })
  .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['Your actualComponent']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Refreshing or re drawing the component use the **[changeDetectionStratergy](https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/)**

so inject the **ChangeDetectionRef** Service in the component where you using the build-in component so on any event call the **detectChange** method for redrawing the component.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best method I found is to use NgZone, like this:

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

onMyChanges() {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    myChanges...
  });
}
```

Read more here : https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Answer (score -1):

call this method whenever you want to reload your page .
that will reload the page

```
 window.location.reload();
```

Comment: this is not good for single page application .

Comment: The idea is reload component without reloading page